# Download data and set it to listview adapter in android

Tags: android

I am building an android app that downloads database records from mysql remote server using Json. I then set the downloaded data to my listview adapter and show it to the user. This implies that, a user can have access to the data only when he is connected to the internet.

Now I want a user to be able to view atmost 20 records from the remote server database even when the he is offline. This also implies that I would have to save some data into the local database and preview it when the user is offline.

```
    MY LOGICS.

    1. I save the newest (20 records) into the local database, anytime the activity loads new set of data from the remote server database

    2. I then truncate the already existing data in the local database to open way for the newest set of data from the remote server. This means, the local database would have the maximum of 20 records at any point in time.

    3. I show these 20 records from the local database to the user anytime there he is offline
```

QUESTION

Please I am doing the above logics to set data into my listview from my remote server database, I want to know if what I am doing is the standard way or there is a standard way of achieving this. I want to achieve the same way as facebook and twitter handles their post or news feed activity. Any idea is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE)